# Disk space not available in RabbitMQ Management plugin

Tags: rabbitmq

I have 2 `RabbitMQ` nodes in the cluster.

I decided to change Disk Space Free Limit in the configuration file to be memory relative as opposed to hard-coded value.

`{disk_free_limit, {mem_relative, 2.0}}`

What I understand is: set a disk free limit (before alarm and block for messages being published) should be 2*RAM memory, in my case `2GB`

`RabbitMQ` seems to work well etc.

The only strange thing is that in the `RabbitMQ Management Pluggin` Disk space column is showing value `(not available)`

[image: RabbitMQ-management-plugin]

Is there a problem that I might not be aware? Or maybe it's just the behavior of `RabbitMQ` for that configuration?

Thank you.

---

Some information about version:

RabbitMQ version: 3.6.0

Erlang version: 7.2.1

Operating System and version: Windows Server 2012R2 Standard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Few things that happened to me.

When `RabbitMQ Management Plugin` disable Disk Space as `(not available)` it won't control the disk space at all.

I think the problem was with setting `mem_relative` on Windows. I changed it to a hardcoded value.

How serious lack of that setting is I found out recently.

Here is the scenario:
Something happened to our `Consumers`, so they stopped to accept any messages. `Publishers` were working normally though. As the result, `RabbitMQ` used all the space available on the box and then failed-over, due to lack of HDD space.

Disk space low watermark supposed to block all the publishers if space on HDD is dropping below, so technically, that prevents `RabbitMQ` from taking all the resources.

Answer (score 0):

In order to diagnose an issue with RabbitMQ you must at least provide this information in addition to the description of your issue:

- RabbitMQ version
- Erlang version
- Operating System and version

Since you haven't provided any of that information, I can only guess at what may be the cause. RabbitMQ uses the `df` command to query free disk space so the command must output data in an unexpected format on your platform.

Comment: sorry, I just added required information to the question.

Comment: No problem! Are you using the English language Windows version? Have you tried a more recent version of RabbitMQ? 3.7.0 shipped yesterday, in fact.

Comment: Yes, its english Windows. Will give it a try, and let you know how that went.